# Hybris Admin User Access

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am using version 6.1. I want to create a user who has most admin capabilities. However I do not want them to have access to creating user groups, users etc. I want them to have access to products etc. Is there a functionality in Backoffice to restrict users from adding users. Is there a way to hid this function in the navigation tree?

THanks

Answer (score 1):

Use Hybris [access rights](https://help.hybris.com/6.1.0/hcd/8b4aa00e866910148df2920f69d68b27.html), for example to give read permissions to user group *mygroup* for item type *User* **(this can be executed as an Impex query)**:

```
$START_USERRIGHTS;;;;;;;;;
Type;UID;MemberOfGroups;Password;Target;read;change;create;remove;change_perm
UserGroup;mygroup;;;;;;;;

;;;;User;+;-;-;-;-;
$END_USERRIGHTS;;;;;
```